# Getting Page URL where your event is raised from

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a asp.net button,

```
protected void myPreciousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //My Logic is happening
     Response.Redirect( What will go here ??);
}
```

How can redirect user to same page ?

**Update**

Reason I am doing this is because I am making some changes to Database and using Asychronize Post Backs but they are not visible in GridView unless I do a page refersh.

I already tried

```
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger
```

and

```
 <asp:PostBackTrigger
```

but no gain only pain

Comment: Question is not very clear. If this is a normal web page, you don't need to redirect, after firing the event, it will load up the same page.

Comment: I updated my question Kaf

Comment: Thank you. I think you have got the answer now. Good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
protected void myPreciousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

If you want to refresh your page;

```
Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get current page url using

```
string Pageurl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```